# Bean validation javax.validation gives javax.persistence.spi::No valid providers found. log message

Tags: java, spring-boot, validation, warnings

Following example code prints out the warning

```
import javax.validation.ConstraintViolation;
import javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException;
import javax.validation.Validation;
import javax.validation.Validator;
import javax.validation.ValidatorFactory;

  var factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
  this.validatorInstance = factory.getValidator();
  validatorInstance.validate(something);
```

Although the validation itself works as expected, I always get the warning

```
javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProviderResolverHolder$DefaultPersistenceProviderResolver log
WARNING: javax.persistence.spi::No valid providers found.
```

The interesting part is that I don't use any JPA, Hibernate or other persistence frameworks within my project.

Does somebody have a clue why this warning comes up?
Every time validate is called for another object the message is logged.